# How to update fixed quantities of a product in cart without breaking a limit per product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have this piece of code that allows me to add fixed quantities to my cart via a dropdown of options. What I need is, whenever I select and add a quantity to the cart, it automatically updates that value in the cart instead of increasing more quantities resulting in over permited quantity per product.

I can limit total quantities on the cart but if i could limit the quantities per product maybe the problem would be solved?

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data = null) {
    global $product;

    $defaults = array(
        'input_name' => array_key_exists('input_name', $data) ? $data['input_name'] : 'quantity',
        'input_value'   => '25',
        'style'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product )
    );

    $lista = array(25, 50, 100, 250);

    $options = '';

    for ( $count = 0; $count < sizeof($lista); $count++) { 
        $valor = $lista[$count];
        $selected = ($valor === $data['input_value']) ? ' selected' : '';
        $options .= '<option value="' . $valor . '"'.$selected.'>' . $valor . ''; }

    echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and the help of some users code here in stackoverflow, i've reached to this.
The combination of this code and the code above, results in an implementation that solves my question. I can set fixed quantities withou exceed a limit per product defined by me. So the problem in incrementing the requested fixed quantity of a certain product without a breaking a limit is solved.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'control_limit_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );

function control_limit_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    //set max quantity per product in cart
    $max_per_product_qty = 250;
    //variable for over quantity verfication
    $over_qty = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        //Get each product id and respective quantity
        $product_identity = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        //Set variable with the requested quantity of some product plus the actual quantity already in cart of that same product 
        $total_quantity_request = $product_quantity + $quantity;

        //compare the quantity of some product in cart to the requested quantity value of that same product
        if( ( $product_identity == $product_id ) && ( ( $product_quantity > $max_per_product_qty ) || ( $total_quantity_request > $max_per_product_qty ) ) ){
            //variable with the name of the product requested
            $product_name = $cart_item['data']->get_name();
            //set variable with true verification for over quantity
            $over_qty = true;
        }
    }

    if( $over_qty ){
        // Result is false==error
        $passed = false;
        // Write msg
         wc_add_notice( __( "You've the amount limit for the product ".$product_name.".", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
    }
    return $passed;
}
```